# Changing Grand total in Excel pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am not sure if it is the right place to ask this question, it would be great if someone can help me on this,
[image]

Above image depicts my problem in simple, I want the grand total should display the count instead of sum, rest should be based on sum, are there any ways to do this?

Regards,
Ram

Comment: you cant change just the grand total, you can add the same field twice tho so you would have SUM and COUNT both with there own individual grand totals

Comment: Thanks, let me try

Comment: I don't think this requirement is feasible, in my tests, both "count" and "sum" will end up showing 8

Comment: Thanks for trying this out at your end.